Maui Prism .CreateWindow() navigation error
I'm working on transitioning a Xamarin.Forms app to Maui. In MauiProgram we call MauiAppBuilder.UsePrism() on the PrismAppBuilder we call .RegisterTypes() to register services and pages for navigation. We've confirmed that the services are getting initialized. At the end, in what was .OnAppStart, we now use .CreateWindow().
.CreateWindow(async (container, navigation) =>
{
    AppCenter.Start("android=guid;ios=guid",
        typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));

    var result = await navigation.NavigateAsync("/AppInitPage");
    if (!result.Success)
    {
        HandleNavigationError(result.Exception);
    }
})

This is resulting in non-successful navigation and resulting in the following exception:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.InvalidNavigationException: 'Expected Navigation Failed. No Root Window has been created.'
PrismAppBuilder:
            .UsePrism(prism =>
                prism
#if ANDROID
                    .RegisterTypes(Platforms.Android.PlatformRegistrations.RegisterPlatformTypes)
#endif
                    .RegisterTypes(containerRegistry =>
                    {
                        Barrel.ApplicationId = AppInfo.Current.PackageName;

                        //Register all of the services
                        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IPreferences>(Preferences.Default);
                        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IConnectivity>(Connectivity.Current);
                        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IAppInfo>(AppInfo.Current);
                        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IDeviceInfo>(DeviceInfo.Current);
                        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IVersionTracking>(VersionTracking.Default);
                        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDb, Db>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAPI, API>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISyncManager, SyncManager>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISyncWorker, SyncWorker>();

                        containerRegistry.Register<IAuthentication, Authentication>();
                        containerRegistry.Register<IEncryptDecrypt, StringEncryptor>();
                        containerRegistry.Register<IHelpers, Helpers>();


                        //Register Pages
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ThemedNavigationPage>("NavigationPage");
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<AboutPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<AppInitPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TermsOfServicePage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CustomerSearchPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingsPage, SettingsPageViewModel>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CustomerPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<FilesPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PhotoPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<CustomerContactPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<AssetPage>();
                        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ProductPage>();

                        //containerRegistry.RegisterGlobalNavigationObserver();

                        App.Container = containerRegistry.GetContainer();

                        App.Container.Resolve<IDb>().InitializeTables();
                    })
                    .AddGlobalNavigationObserver(context => context.Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        if (x.Type == NavigationRequestType.Navigate)
                            Console.WriteLine($"Navigation: {x.Uri}");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine($"Navigation: {x.Type}");

                        var status = x.Cancelled ? "Cancelled" : x.Result.Success ? "Success" : "Failed";
                        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {status}");

                        if (status == "Failed" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Result?.Exception?.Message))
                            Console.Error.WriteLine(x.Result.Exception.Message);
                    }))
                    .OnInitialized(_ =>
                    {
                        Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.VersionTracking.Track();
                    })
                    .CreateWindow(async (container, navigation) =>
                    {
                        AppCenter.Start("android=guid;ios=guid",
                            typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));

                        var result = await navigation.NavigateAsync("/AppInitPage");
                        if (!result.Success)
                        {
                            HandleNavigationError(result.Exception);
                        }
                    })
            );

Exception stack:
[DOTNET] Navigation: http://localhost/AppInitPage
[DOTNET] Result: Failed
[DOTNET] A dependency issue occurred while resolving the ViewModel. Check the InnerException for the ContainerResolutionException
[DOTNET] Prism.Navigation.NavigationException: A dependency issue occurred while resolving the ViewModel. Check the InnerException for the ContainerResolutionException
[DOTNET]  ---> Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelCreationException: Unable to Create ViewModel for 'myApp.Views.AppInitPage'.
[DOTNET]  ---> Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException: An unexpected error occurred while resolving 'myApp.ViewModels.AppInitPageViewModel'
[DOTNET]  ---> DryIoc.ContainerException: code: Error.UnableToResolveFromRegisteredServices;
[DOTNET] message: Unable to resolve resolution root myApp.ViewModels.AppInitPageViewModel with passed arguments [Constant(Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.Dispatcher, typeof(Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.Dispatcher))]
[DOTNET]   from container with scope {Name=null}
[DOTNET]  with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients, FuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration, SelectLastRegisteredFactory} and without {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient}
[DOTNET]  with FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory
[DOTNET]  with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}
[DOTNET]   with normal and dynamic registrations:
[DOTNET]   (DefaultDynamicKey(0), {FactoryID=869, ImplType=myApp.ViewModels.AppInitPageViewModel, Reuse=TransientReuse, HasCondition})
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 14774
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Container.TryThrowUnableToResolve(Request request) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 933
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory(Request request) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 915
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheKeyed(Int32 serviceTypeHash, Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, Object scopeName, Type requiredServiceType, Request preResolveParent, Object[] args) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 510
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, Object serviceKey, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, Type requiredServiceType, Request preResolveParent, Object[] args) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 469
[DOTNET]    at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve(IResolver resolver, Type serviceType, Object[] args, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, Type requiredServiceType, Object serviceKey) in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:line 8673
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Container.DryIoc.DryIocScopedProvider.Resolve(Type type, ValueTuple`2[] parameters) in /_/src/Prism.Container.DryIoc/DryIocScopedProvider.cs:line 54
[DOTNET]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Container.DryIoc.DryIocScopedProvider.Resolve(Type type, ValueTuple`2[] parameters) in /_/src/Prism.Container.DryIoc/DryIocScopedProvider.cs:line 58
[DOTNET]    at Prism.PrismAppBuilder.DefaultViewModelLocator(Object view, Type viewModelType) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\PrismAppBuilder.cs:line 118
[DOTNET]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[DOTNET]    at Prism.PrismAppBuilder.DefaultViewModelLocator(Object view, Type viewModelType) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\PrismAppBuilder.cs:line 126
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(Object view, Action`2 setDataContextCallback) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Prism.Core\Mvvm\ViewModelLocationProvider.cs:line 136
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.Autowire(Object view) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Mvvm\ViewModelLocator.cs:line 85
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Mvvm.ViewRegistryBase.Autowire(BindableObject view) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Mvvm\ViewRegistryBase.cs:line 25
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Mvvm.ViewRegistryBase`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].CreateView(IContainerProvider container, String name) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Prism.Core\Mvvm\ViewRegistryBase{TBaseView}.cs:line 51
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.CreatePage(String segmentName) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 903
[DOTNET]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.CreatePage(String segmentName) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 920
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.CreatePageFromSegment(String segment) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 943
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigationForRootPage(String nextSegment, Queue`1 segments, INavigationParameters parameters, Nullable`1 useModalNavigation, Nullable`1 animated) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 589
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigation(Page currentPage, Queue`1 segments, INavigationParameters parameters, Nullable`1 useModalNavigation, Nullable`1 animated) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 486
[DOTNET]    at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.NavigateAsync(Uri uri, INavigationParameters parameters) in D:\a\Prism\Prism\src\Maui\Prism.Maui\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:line 378
**Microsoft.Maui.Controls.InvalidNavigationException:** 'Expected Navigation Failed. No Root Window has been created.'

We've been through each dependency on the AppInitPage to ensure that the dependencies and services that it's trying to use are all built out. We should then expect that the constructor of the AppInitPage is called, however this is not happening and thus the navigation keeps failing. The same MauiProgram (except it uses OnAppStart instead of CreateWindow) is at use in another app and works without issues.

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.InvalidNavigationException: 'Expected Navigation Failed. No Root Window has been created.' About this error, you can see the issue: No Root Window has been created #3079. It's the same error, but not be fixed. You can reported this on GitHub.

You should first try not using absolute navigation for the root page, you are already navigating absolutely (navigationService.NavigateAsync("AppInitPage").
Next try unregistering the viewmodel and seeing if the page loads. The stack trace indicates prism wasn't able to create the a dependency for that viewmodel so you will have to debug that code manually to find the dependency that has failed to be created!
If this is a port, ensure your platform services are being registered if you had any in the platform initialisers!

It ended up being an unregistered service (the monkeycache barrel), that was causing the problem. Once we registered that everything worked as expected. Thanks!

Well, according to your comment, as a wiki answer:

This is resulting in non-successful navigation and resulting in the
following exception:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.InvalidNavigationException: 'Expected
Navigation Failed. No Root Window has been created.'

Registering service (the monkeycache barrel) can avoid this error.
